# Python update a json file by a string

Tags: python, json

I need to insert a path inside a json and be able to update in the future, currently the code is

```
def save_json(direc):
  try:
    if not os.path.exists('../resources/data.json'):
      os.mknod('../resources/data.json')
      f = open('../resources/data.json', 'a+')
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    if os.stat("../resources/data.json").st_size == 0:
      f = open('../resources/data.json', 'a+')
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    print(" ")
    #obj.append({"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false"}}}}}})
    with open('../resources/data.json', 'r+') as myfile:
      data=myfile.read()
      myfile.close()
    obj = json.loads(data)
    print(direc)
```

I'm trying to put this json

```
{"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"downloaded":false,"moved":false}}}}}}
```

and next time I will want to add this json in a way where I take the path that I passed as a parameter that would be this /2015/08/26/23365116/23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat

```
({"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_HORARIA_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false"}}}}}}
```

Comment: The path isn't relative to the directory you want, it's relative to the current working directory.

Comment: the directories are ok, what I need is to be able to dynamically add a json into the file

Comment: JSON is just a data-interchange format, and there's a lot of "redish flags" in your code. You can just serialize any simple list/int/float/dict/string data object to JSON no issue, once you have the object in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Saving python dictionaries as `.json`

Let's say you want to save the dictionary saved in a variable `my_dict`

```py
import json

my_dict = {
  'a': {
    'wow': 'very nice'
  }
}

with open('myJsonFile.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(my_dict, f)
```

## Navigating nested dictionaries using `toolz`

`toolz` is a python library that provides many useful utility functions especially if you want to do functional programming, but the provided utility functions can be useful whether you are programming functionally or not. We'll be using the `toolz.dicttoolz.get_in` function to easily navigate a nested dictionary.

```py
from toolz.dicttoolz import get_in

my_dict = {
    '2015': {
        '08': {
            '26': {
                '23365116': {
                    '23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat': {
                        'downloaded': False, 'moved': False
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dict_path = '/2015/08/26/23365116/23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat'.split('/')
# dict_path is sliced from 1 on wards to avoid the '' since the string starts with a /
res = get_in(dict_path[1:], my_dict)
print('res:', res)
```

## Navigating nested dictionaries without external libraries

If you don't want to install any further libraries you can also just use a self-made implementation

```py
my_dict = {
    '2015': {
        '08': {
            '26': {
                '23365116': {
                    '23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat': {
                        'downloaded': False, 'moved': False
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def get_in(d_path, target_dict, default=None, no_default=False):
    for key in d_path:
        try:
            target_dict = target_dict[key]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            if no_default:
                raise
            return default
    return target_dict


dict_path = '/2015/08/26/23365116/23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat'.split('/')
# dict_path is sliced from 1 on wards to avoid the '' since the string starts with a /
res = get_in(dict_path[1:], my_dict)
print('res:', res)
```

## `open` as a context manager

the built-in function `open` is a context manager which means it supports `with`  syntax:

```py
with <context manager> as <res>:
  <wrapped code>
```

using `with`-syntax with the `open` context manager allows you to open files without having to worry about closing the file and handling errors

the following code:

```py
with open('file-path.ext', 'w') as f:
  # <code>
```

is basically equivalent to:

```py
f = open('file-path.ext', 'w')
try:
  # <code>
except Exception as err:
  f.close()
  raise
else:
  f.close()
```

That's why it is highly recommended that you take advantage of this because it reduces boiler-plate, makes your code safer and cleaner.

With this list of tips you are hopefully equipped to solve your problem more effectively. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code, and this won't fully solve the issue, but it will help you understand what's going wrong.

```
import os
import json

def save_json(direc):
    path = os.path.join(direc, '../resources/data.json')
    # It's fine to overwrite the file if it's empty.
    # Also, you should probably **try*** to read the data, 
    # and if you can't and the error is no such file exists,
    # then write to it. `os.path.exists` is an antipattern.
    if not os.path.exists(path) or os.stat(path).st_size == 0:
        # mknod is not available on Windows. Consider having portable code.
        # always use `with open()` to automatically close the file
        # when leaving the with statement.
        # Use W+ to create a new file with writing.
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump({}, f)
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
        obj = json.load(f)
        # Don't need to close, will be handled automatically.

    # Do what you want with object.
    obj["2015"] = {"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"downloaded":false,"moved":false}}}}}

    # Now, finally, serialize it back.
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(obj, f)
```

Comment: so if i add the following json  ```{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_22-01.dat":{"downloaded":false,"moved":false}}}}} ```
can I keep the 2 data together in the file?

Comment: You don't add "JSON". JSON is an interchange format: it's a serialized data format and not what Python stores in memory, it just acts very similar to objects common to most languages.

Comment: You manipulate the object in-memory (IE, add items to the dict, append to the list), then re-serialize it to disk. JSON is merely a data interchange format.